# Is this a good practice to use SQLite select query in custom ArrayAdapter to check each and every row while scrolling list view in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an array list below where data is coming from cloud server.

```
protected ArrayList<ProductList> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String sObject  = params[0];
        String result=null;
        String mUrl = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        ClassReadingWritngApi data_class = new ClassReadingWritngApi();
        String Mydata = data_class.SendData(mUrl,sObject);
        if (Mydata != null) {
            try {
                pList= new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray MainArray = new JSONArray(Mydata);
                JSONObject Obj0 = MainArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String Data = Obj0.getString("ReturnData");
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Data);
                JSONArray Arr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("GetHdItems");
                for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = Arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    pList.add(new ProductList(jsonObject.getString("stock_code"),jsonObject.getString("stock_desc"),
                            jsonObject.getString("imglink"),"0"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return pList;
    }
```

I also have some data stored in local database (SQLite) and I need to join this with above array list to cross check.
So I am trying to get data from SQLite in custom ArrayAdapter like below.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {

           ..........

        final ProductList Item = pList.get(position);

        holder.Item_desc.setText(Item.getItemDesc());
        String imglink = Item.getImgLink();
        final String StockCode = Item.getItemCode();
        String QtyNow  = Item.getOrderQty();
```

> String oldQty  = db.mSelectOrederQty(StockCode);

```
        if (oldQty == null)
            oldQty="0";

        final String mQty;
        if (QtyNow != "0"){
            mQty = QtyNow;
        }else{
            mQty = oldQty;
        }

        holder.txt_qty.setText(mQty);}
```

It's working, but it seems this is wrong because while scrolling list view, every time SQLite is being called.
Please advice is it okay or any other solution.

Comment: "while scrolling list view, every time SQLite is being called" This will slow down your app.  You should load all the data beforehand.  Reading from a database or the file system or any external source is slower than accessing data from memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practise to have any database operation in get view.  As it is not meant for it and it's slow down the rendering and scrolling.

I would suggest to iterate through the product and populate oldstockquantiy Hashmap with key being StockCode and value being the oldQuantity. This you can do when you initially set the adapter to the list view.  So instead of reading from database in get view you can read from Hashmap by providing the StockCode, which is much faster.

Many other way also exists but this is more simpler.

I hope it will help you.